# Difference between sending mass email once and single email several times?

Tags: email

What is the difference between sending a mass email once and sending a single email multiple times.  What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Are you referring to sending the emails from Apex, or from the UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Mass Emailing

Pros

1. Is generally faster for the user (you go through a wizard once instead of once per contact.)

Cons

1. Cannot customize the email template on a per-contact basis
2. Might not be able to create a filter to select the recipients
3. Visualforce email templates [cannot be used](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_visualforce_email_templates.htm)

## Individual Emailing

Pros

1. Can customize the email template before sending if you select a text template
2. Does not require Extended Mail Merge to be activated
3. Does not require a filter to select recipient

Cons

1. Time consuming for a large number of emails

Comment: I think a big difference is that you can't use a visual force template for mass email. So you have to use individual email.  I was wondering is there any difference in limits?

Comment: I added that con, @dublintech, but if you think of others feel free to update this answer - that's why I marked it as a community wiki.

Comment: @Mike Chale great idea.